# Count the length of messages from the same user

Tags: javascript

I have an array called `users` that includes an object, which looks like this:

```
'user': {
    'name': name,
    'msg': msg          
}
```

It is possible that in that array a user ist listed multiple times. 
I would like to count the length of all his messages (`msg`).

This is how I tried it:

```
score = [];
for (i of users) {
    for (s of score) {
        if (s.name === i.user.name) {
            score.push({
                'name': i.user.name,
                'counter': i.user.msg.length
            });
        }
        else {
            s.counter = s.counter + i.user.msg.length;
        }
    }       
}
```

The array `score` which also includes an object should only include unique users. So they shouldn't be listed twice.

Anyway, that doesn't work and I am not very happy with my code, because there must be a better and an easier solution.

Comment: show your expected output

Comment: if array score has unique users, why not convert it to one dictionary with users.unique_id or users.name (if name unique) first? then only need to loop array=users to get the result you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to convert scores into a map of all the unique values.
Once you have that map, if you want you can convert that into an array.

```js
const users = [
  {
    name: 'user1',
    msg: 'hello',
  },
  {
    name: 'user1',
    msg: 'hello2',
  },
  {
    name: 'user2',
    msg: 'world',
  },
  {
    name: 'user2',
    msg: 'world2',
  },
  {
    name: 'user3',
    msg: 'foo',
  },
];

const scores = users.reduce((scores, {name, msg}) => {
  if (!scores[name]) {
    scores[name] = { name, counter: 0 };
  }
  scores[name].counter += msg.length;
  return scores;
}, {});

// Now convert to an array if you want
console.log(Object.entries(scores));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use object instead of array for `score` and use `user.name` as key:

```
const score = {};

for (const user of users) {
  if (score[user.name]) {
    score[user.name].counter += user.msg.length;
  } else {
    score[user.name] = {
      name: user.name, 
      counter: user.msg.length,
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to bug you here, but why did you delete [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49929041/1048572)?

Comment: Well as I got downvoted, I thought there is something wrong, so I deleted it. There was an error indeed (one extra line), fixed that now and undeleted it. Still not really sure why the downvote :/

Comment: My guess is that someone downvoted the question, for being of poor quality, and downvoted the answer for answering a poor question. Don't take downvotes too serious, they judge "usefulness" over "correctness" - if you think that your answer is useful, don't delete it and ignore the downvote (if there was a mistake, a comment should have pointed it out). I would have answered exactly the same :-)